# Convert word files to pdfs and then merge pdfs

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to convert some words to pdfs and then merge the pdfs. I'm having trouble with the merging part where I get an empty pdf file. Because I'm doing the merging at the directory that has the word files I use path.endwith(".pdf") to merge only the pdf files. The code is as below:

```
import os
import win32com.client
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger

path = (r'C:\Mytest\trials')
word_file_names = []
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for f in filenames:  
        if f.lower().endswith(".docx") :
            new_name = f.replace(".docx", ".pdf")
            in_file =(dirpath + '/'+ f)
            new_file =(dirpath + '/' + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
        if f.lower().endswith(".doc"):
            new_name = f.replace(".doc", ".pdf")
            in_file =(dirpath +'/' + f)
            new_file =(dirpath +'/' + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
word.Quit()



merger = PdfMerger()
pdfs = os.scandir(r'C:\Mytest\trials')

for pdf in pdfs:
    if path.endswith(".pdf"):
        merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("merged.pdf")
merger.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found a way that worked. Sorry for not posting it sooner.

```
merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()

for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        merger.append(file)
merger.write("merged.pdf")
merger.close()
```